# ¿Cómo puedo insertar y recibir los datos que inserto mediante ajax en php?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Tengo un botón, al presionarlo quiero **insertar** en la base de datos mysql, los valores a insertar son 2 cuyos valores ya están por **default**, por lo cual, no tengo data para enviar (los valores son a y b), luego de insertar estos datos quiero que me muestre 'una mesa' en la misma pantalla, cuya estructura está en html y dentro de su estructura hay un campo

en el cual quiero que me **retorne** y **muestre** el **valor b** que se ingresó por default. Gracias este es mi ajax:

```js
//Este es mi funcion ajax
function agregarMesa(){
    $.ajax({
        data: "",
        url: 'Controlador/mesa.controlador.php',
        type: 'POST',
        beforeSend: function(){            
        },
        success: function(respuesta){
          //Esta es la mesa dibujada
            var imagen_mesa = $("#mesa");
            var nueva_imagen_mesa = '<div>\n\
                            <input id="nro_mesa" value=""         disabled>\n\
                            <a href="#">\n\
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="Vista/img/contenido/mesa.png">\n\
                            </a>\n\
                            <div clas="col-md-8">\n\
                                <button class="btn btn-success"></button>\n\
                            </div>\n\
                        </div>';
            imagen_mesa.append(nueva_imagen_mesa);
        }
    });
}

 //Acá capturo cuando se presiona el botón
$('#agregarMesa').on('click', function(){
    agregarMesa();
});
```

```css
//Esto es en el controlador php
public function ctrAjaxAgregarMesa(){
            $tip_recibe = $_POST["tip"];
            echo '<script>alert('+$tip_recibe+');</script>';
            echo '<script>alert("holi");</script>';
            if($tip_recibe == "top"){
                $tabla = "Mesa";
                $resultado = MesaModelo::agregarMesa($tabla);
                if($resultado == "ok"){
                    echo "<script>LISTO </script>";
                }
            }
 }
 
 
 //esto es el modelo php
 static public function ultimaMesaAgregada($tabla){
            $consulta = "SELECT MAX(id_mesa) FROM $tabla";
            $statement = Conexion::Conectar()->prepare($consulta);
            $statement->execute();
            return $statement->fetch();
            $statement->close();
            $statement = null;
        }
        
        static public function agregarMesa($tabla){
            $ultimaMesa = MesaModelo::ultimaMesaAgregada($tabla);
            $dato_ultimaMesa = $ultimaMesa + 1;
            $consulta = "INSERT INTO $tabla(numero_mesa) values :nro_mesa";
            $statement = Conexion::Conectar()->prepare($consulta);
            $statement->bindParam(":nro_mesa", $dato_ultimaMesa, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            
            if($statement->execute()){
                return "ok";
            }else{
                return "error";
            }            
            
            $statement -> close();
            $statement = null;
}
```

```html
    <div class="row"> <!-- ESTE HTML CONTENDRÁ LAS MESAS CREADAS -->
        <div class="row" style=" margin: 5%; padding: 2%;">
            <div id="mesa" class="row">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- ESTE HTML CONTIENE EL BOTON QUE SE PRESIONARA -->
    <div class="row">
        <button id="agregarMesa" name="btn_agregarMesa">
        </button>
    </div>
```

Comment: En tu controlador, todo ocurre dentro de esta función: `ctrAjaxAgregarMesa()`, la cual **nunca es llamada**, por lo que nunca se ejecutará. Para llamarla, debes hacerlo al principo del controlador: `ctrAjaxAgregarMesa();` Por cierto, yo quitaría todos los  `alert` que tienes ahí, retornando solamente el resultado de la petición al servidor y nada más. Si quieres mostrar `alert`, hazlo del otro lado, en el `success`, no en el servidor. Lo mismo con esto: `echo "<script>LISTO CTMR</script>";` no sé para que usas `script` ahí. Es preciso entender que Ajax trabajará mejor con datos, cadenas, etc.

Comment: Debo llamar a la función empezando la clase controlador? . Ejem: class ControladorMesa{  //aquí llamaría a la función ctrAjaxAgregarMesa() ...Resto de funciones...} ??

Comment: Si es una clase entonces debes crear una instancia de la misma y llamar al método pasándole los datos posteados.

Comment: Sí, tenías razón. lo llamé en un if($_SERVER('REQUEST_METHOS')=='POST'){} y dentro lo instancié y llamé a la función. Muchas Gracias.